# Should you unit test constructors of abstract classes and, if so, how?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

Supposing you have an abstract base class like this:

```
public abstract class WebApiServiceBase
    {
        public WebApiServiceBase(
            HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            HttpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
        }

        protected HttpClient HttpClient { get; }

// For brevity, omitted some instance methods that can be used by derived classes
}
```

The class knows it needs the HttpClient in the constructor so it throws an error if it's null. Should this error-throwing functionality be unit tested?

If so, what's the best way, seeing as you can't directly instantiate an abstract class in your unit tests like this:

```
    [TestClass()]
    public class WebApiServiceBaseTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void WebApiServiceBase_NullHttpClient_ThrowsArgumentNull()
        {
            //Arrange
            Action action = () => {
                var controller = new WebApiServiceBase(null); // Won't compile, of course, because you can't directly instantiate an abstract class
            };

            //Act
            //Assert
            Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentNullException>(action);
        }
    }
```

I understand there are many things I *could* do:

- Only test the error-throwing functionality in derived classes.
- Invent a new derived class in the test code just for testing this.
- Don't make classes like this abstract in the first place.
- Probably some other ideas I haven't thought of too.

But what *should* I do? What's the *best practice*?

Comment: The idea that there's one *right* answer here is a little odd.

Comment: Well the whole purpose of writing unit tests is getting code coverage and having a system in place on where you can easily validate whether or not the changes you make doesnt break anything in the system. Since your class is abstract and never will be instantiated I see no point trying to test it. You do test this funcionallity in derived classes, which implicitly tests your base class

Comment: But Jochem, couldn't you also argue that, since none of the derived classes throws the ArgumentNullException, you probably wouldn't think to unit test for it in the derived classes either, and so you might forget to test it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but it's a bit dodgy.The constructor exception doesn't happen until you try to accesss some property of the mock. It does confirm that something is throwing the exception you want though.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void WebApiServiceBase_NullHttpClient_ThrowsArgumentNull()
    {

        var controller = new Mock<WebApiServiceBase>(MockBehavior.Loose, 
            //Pass null in to the constructor
            null
            );

        var exception = Assert.ThrowsException<TargetInvocationException>(() =>
        {
            var httpClient = controller.Object.HttpClient;
        });

        Assert.IsTrue(exception.InnerException is ArgumentNullException ane && ane.ParamName == "httpClient");
    }
}
```

But, you shouldn't design your classes like this because it makes them hard to test. Better to inject all the reusable code instead of making a base class. A good Http client abstraction would mean that you don't need to create a base class. Here is a good abstraction:

```
public interface IClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a strongly typed request to the server and waits for a strongly typed response
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResponseBody">The expected type of the response body</typeparam>
    /// <param name="request">The request that will be translated to a http request</param>
    /// <returns>The response as the strong type specified by TResponseBody /></returns>
    /// <typeparam name="TRequestBody"></typeparam>
    Task<Response<TResponseBody>> SendAsync<TResponseBody, TRequestBody>(IRequest<TRequestBody> request);

    /// <summary>
    /// Default headers to be sent with http requests
    /// </summary>
    IHeadersCollection DefaultRequestHeaders { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Base Uri for the client. Any resources specified on requests will be relative to this.
    /// </summary>
    AbsoluteUrl BaseUri { get; }
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net/blob/6762a4510495f2fceb3c3ae6c7b81eae65f546ee/src/RestClient.Net.Abstractions/IClient.cs#L9)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with your second option (have a derived class just for testing purposes). If you use a derived class from your domain, that might be removed later while the abstract class is still used by others. Then the test would not compile anymore. Having a class for this explicit testcase would therefore make more sense.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation and logical justification